# Iterate over cells in a CSV file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, parsing

I have a CSV file: "myCSV.csv" with two columns: "first" and "second".

All the data inside is just numbers. So the file looks like this:

```
first, second
138901801, 849043027
389023890, 382903205
749029820, 317891093
...
```

I would like to iterate over these numbers and perform some custom parsing on them, then store results in an array.

How can I achieve a behavior like the following?

```
const parsedData = [];

for (const row of file) {
  parsedData.push(row[0].toString() + row[1].toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with a file the user has selected in the browser, you'd make a FileReader in response to the user's action. (See [FileReader - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).)

---

But it sounds like you already have the file on your server, in which case you'd use Node's built-in File System module. (See [File System - NodeJS](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-fs-module).)

If you just want the module's `readFile` function, you'd require it in your file like:

```
const {readFile} = require("fs");
```

And you'd use it to process a text file like:

```
readFile("myFile.txt", "utf8", (error, textContent) => {
  if(error){ throw error; }
  const parsedData = [];
  for(let row of textContent.split("\n")){
    const rowItems = row.split(",");
    parsedData.push(rowItems[0].toString() + rowItems[1].toString());
  }
}
```

(See [Node.js - Eloquent JavaScript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/20_node.html)).

---

However, if you want to handle your CSV directly as binary data (rather than converting to a text file before reading), you'd need to add something like this before invoking `readFile`:

```
const textContent = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buffer));
```

...with the `textContent` parameter in the arrow function replaced by a `buffer` parameter to handle the binary data.
(If `Uint16Array` is the wrong size, it might be `Uint8Array` instead. See [Buffer to String - Google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String).)

---

You might also find these resources helpful:
[JS CSV Tutorial - SeegateSite](https://seegatesite.com/tutorial-read-and-write-csv-file-with-javascript/)
[JS read-text demo - GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-program-to-read-text-file/)