# How to split csv file into multiple array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a two csv files and the difference stored  in another file. my code is working but the difference stored like full line not a particular data. How to solve the problem. I want to split a csv file into array. Then compared the values.

```
const fs = require("fs");

const generateNewFile = (
  pathToFirstFile,
  pathToSecondFile,
  pathForOutputFile = "./compare.csv"
) => {
  let firstFile = "",
    secondFile = "",
    compareLine = "";
  //@ts-ignore
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const firstFileReadStream = fs.createReadStream(pathToFirstFile);
    firstFileReadStream
      //@ts-ignore
      .on("data", (data1) => {
        firstFile = firstFile + data1;
      })
      //@ts-ignore
      .on("error", (err) => reject(err))
      .on("end", () => {
        const secondFileReadStream = fs.createReadStream(pathToSecondFile);
        secondFileReadStream
          //@ts-ignore
          .on("data", (data2) => {
            secondFile = secondFile + data2;
          })
          //@ts-ignore
          .on("error", (err) => reject(err))
          .on("end", () => {
            const file1 = firstFile.toString().split("\n");
            const file2 = secondFile.toString().split("\n");
            //@ts-ignore
            let file = {};
            //@ts-ignore
            file2.forEach((line) => (file[line] = true));
            file1.forEach((iLine) => {
              //@ts-ignore
              if (!file[iLine]) compareLine = compareLine + iLine + "\n";
            });
            fs.writeFileSync(pathForOutputFile, compareLine);
            resolve("DONE");
          });
      });
  });
};
(async () => {
  console.time("csv comparison");
  console.log(await generateNewFile("./file1.csv", "./file2.csv"));
  console.timeEnd("csv comparison completed");
})();
```

`Firstname,Lastname,Email,MobileNumber Kamala,Ganesh,kamaga.6454@gmail.com,9485783674`
first file

`Firstname,Lastname,Email,MobileNumber Kamala,Ganesh,kamaga.6454@gmail.com,9485783673`
second file

`Kamala,Ganesh,kamaga.6454@gmail.com,9485783674`
third file
it's stored full line not particular data.

Comment: What should the third file contain?

Comment: difference is mobile number. so the third file stored mobile number only

Comment: I made it...   const file1 = firstFile.toString().replace(/\n/g, ",").split(',');
                    const file2 = secondFile.toString().replace(/\n/g, ",").split(',');

Comment: just add the .replace(/\n/g, ",") line, only the difference data stored

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65477134/iterate-over-cells-in-a-csv-file-in-node-js/65478327#65478327) can help some. (You use something like `for(let row of textContent.split("\n"))` to separate the rows -- and the bottom part shows how to handle the `buffer` object that `fs` gets from a binary CSV file.)